# Python Text-based Game Equip Armor Stats

Tags: python, statistics

I'm working on a Python text-based rpg and ran into a problem I can't figure out how to fix. I'm trying to get a system that is constantly updating to tell the player what his/her stats should be depending on the armor or weapon equipped.
here is an sample of the class from my code:

```
import sys
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.weap = "Rusty Sword"
        self.armH = "None"
        self.armB = "Wor Shirt"
        self.armA = "None"
        self.armL = "Worn Pants"
        self.armF = "Worn Boots"
        self.gold = 100
        self.stre = 1
        self.magi = 0
        self.rang = 0
        self.defe = 0
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.maxexp = 100
        self.pots = 0
        self.arrows = 0
        self.inventory = ["Rusty Sword", 
                          "Worn Shirt", 
                          "Worn Pants", 
                          "Worn Boots"]
        self.spells = []
## Armor and Weapon Stats #####
    ## WEAPON BUFFS ##
        if self.weap == "Rusty Sword":
            self.stre += 10 
        if self.weap != "Rusy Sword":
             self.stre -= 10
```

The bottom code shows if you have a certain item equip
it will change your stats but the problem I have currently is when
you unequip armor or weapons it doesn't decrease or even change your stats
like it is supposed to. Basically I'm just figuring out a way to create an updating system that updates the player's stats accordingly depending on what items the have equipped.

Comment: Why not make e.g. `stre` a `@property` calculated when needed, rather than adding to and subtracting from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like each character has a *base* attribute score, but the *effective* score is the base modified by various pieces of equipment. This is a good use case for a property.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # ...
        self.base_stre = 1
        # ...

    @property
    def stre(self):
        stre = self.base_stre
        if self.weap == "Rusty Sword":
            stre += 10
        # etc
        return str
```

Comment: After I add the @property and change stre to a method in Player how would I call upon it for use in something like viewable stats so the player knows how much attack or defense they have? Basically I'm asking how would I print stre?

Comment: Properties are accessed just like plain attributes (`print p.stre`); the only difference is that instead of being a simple lookup (`p.__dict__['stre']`), it's now the return value of a method call.